# Create trigger to check whether same day or not in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I have a table Reservation:

```
id_guest |id_room|date_in |day_out |
    1    |1      |1/1/2019|1/5/2019|
    2    |2      |1/3/2019|1/5/2019|
    3    |1      |1/2/2019|1/4/2019| invalid
```

`id_guest` 3 is not valid because you cannot book a room that has already been rented.

So I want to create trigger to prevent that.

Comment: Assuming you still want a trigger, I recommend you read the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and then have a go at writing a trigger, and then ask a question when you get stuck.

Comment: @DaleK beside trigger so Do you have another way to do that?

Comment: As its likely to be a common issue (I imagine?) I would probably create a stored procedure to insert into that table, and as part of the stored procedure check that the booking is still valid to go ahead, keeping the table locked during this time so that nothing changes between checking that its valid and inserting the booking. That allows you to handle the failure in a cleaner manner. However I guess a trigger would work.

Comment: How to best handle this form of concurrency is quite a complex challenge which will require quite a lot of research.

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but this should get you close.  The logic is fairly straightforward.  Just a simple collision check.  I have to agree with the comment however that it's usually better to check this type of "business rule" as part of a stored proc, or within the app tier, but you asked for a trigger so providing sample logic in the form of a trigger.

```
CREATE TRIGGER VerifyResDate ON dbo.Reservation  
AFTER INSERT  
AS  
IF EXISTS (
           SELECT * FROM dbo.Reservation R
           INNER JOIN Inserted I
           ON I.room_id = R.room_id AND -- same room
              I.user_id <> R.user_id AND -- different user
             (I.DateIn <= R.DayOut AND I.DayOut >= DateIn) -- overlap
          )  
BEGIN  
     RAISERROR ('Another guest has this room on those dates.', 16, 1);  
     ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;  
     RETURN   
END;  
GO
```

Also, this protects inserts only.  Depending on how your application works, someone could come in later and update an existing reservation and change a valid date to an invalid one after original insert.  So you may want to include "after update" as part of your trigger.

Comment: `AFTER INSERT` means the new rows are already in the table. They'll overlap with themselves. Also, you're overcomplicating your overlap checks - two periods overlap if the first starts before the second ends and the second starts before the first ends. You don't have to break down into various separate cases.

Comment: @RThomas now I cannot insert anything including the thing that satisfy condition above.even though I have written ``` DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS Reservation.VerifyResDate``` I still cannot insert anything into Reservation

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - good call on the behavior of after insert, needed an additional condition on different user.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - also, clever overlap logic - duh

Comment: @TuyếnNguyễnThị - check your use of schema name in your drop - you can just drop directly - you don't need the if exists - that will also reveal an error message that will tell you if you got the wrong name.